# How to count a variable using a for loop?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm designing a program that simulates a game of dice. The code calculates the total points get each round and the player that wins each round.

I am trying to get **the overall number of wins and the total points**. I tried using a for loop in the main class but I wasn't sure how to implement it in this problem.

> Round 1:
>
> player 1   3 1 5 points: 9
>
> player 2   2 6 6 points: 14
>
> Winner is player 2
>
> Round 2:
>
> player 1   3 6 5 points: 14
>
> player 2   2 3 2 points: 7
>
> Winner is player 1
>
> Round 3:
>
> player 1   3 3 6 points: 12
>
> player 2   5 4 6 points: 15
>
> Winner is player 2

.

> **Total wins: player 1-->1/ player 2-->2**
>
> **Total points:  player 1-->35/ player 2-->36**

**Main class**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {
  // ------------------- FIELDS ------------------------    
        // Create instance of Scanner class
        public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        // variables
        public static ThreeDiceScorer thrdiesc;

        public static int diceArray [];

    // ------------------ METHODS ------------------------  
        public static void main(String[] args) {

        int rounds; // input by user
        int players;  // input by user

        System.out.print("Please input number of rounds (grater or equal than 0) --> ");
        rounds = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\n");

        System.out.print("Please input number of players (grater or equal than 2) --> ");
        players = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("\n");


         for (int r = 0; r < rounds; r++) { // loop for number of rounds
        int max = 0;
        int max_p = 0;
        System.out.println("Round " + (r+1) + ": ");
        for (int p = 0; p < players; p++) { //loop for players
            int diceArray[] = new int[3];
        for (int i = 0; i < diceArray.length; i++) { // loop for dice Array (data of Array)
        diceArray [i] = 1 + (int)(6 * Math.random());   
        }
        // Create new ThreeDice and calculator instances
        thrdiesc = new ThreeDiceScorer(diceArray [0], diceArray [1], diceArray [2]);

        //Calculate
        thrdiesc.calcTotalPoints();
        thrdiesc.printResult(p, r);
            if (thrdiesc.total > max) {
                max = thrdiesc.total;
                max_p = p;
            }
            }
         System.out.println("Winner is player " + (max_p + 1) + "\n");
            }
        System.out.println("Total wins: " );
        System.out.println("Total points: " );

    }//end Main Method  
} // end Class
```

**Calculation class**

```
public class ThreeDiceScorer {
     public static int total;
     public int die1;
     public int die2;
     public int die3;

     public ThreeDiceScorer(int s1, int s2, int s3) {
          die1 = s1;
          die2 = s2;
          die3 = s3;
     }
public void calcTotalPoints() {
    int sumOfDice = die1 + die2 + die3;
         total= sumOfDice;
    }

      public void printResult(int p, int r) {
        System.out.println("player " + (p + 1) + "   " + die1 + " " + die2 + " " + die3 + " " + "points: " + total);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried using a for loop in the main class but I wasn't sure how to implement it in this problem.

I would say, do one thing at a time. Test your implementation and once you confirmed that it is working, then move on. The sequential steps to reach your goal would be:

**Steps**

1. Implement dice rolling for ***one*** player first. (Can do it in a method)
2. Call the above implemented method for 2nd player's dice roll.
3. Decide winner
4. Once steps 1-3 were implemented correctly, enclose steps 1-3 within a loop (preferable a `for-loop` for this particular case)

   ```
   //Example:
   int numOfRounds = 3;  //can receive this from user input

   for(int x=0; x<numOfRounds; x++){
       rollDice(playerOne);
       rollDice(playerTwo);
       decideWinner(playerOne, playerTwo);
   }
   ```
5. Once steps 1-4 is tested and working fine. Implement the display of total score:

   ```
   //Example:
   int numOfRounds = 3;  //can receive this from user input
   for(int x=0; x<numOfRounds; x++){
       rollDice(playerOne);
       rollDice(playerTwo);
       decideWinner(playerOne, playerTwo);            
   }
   displayFinalScore();
   ```

Total score and total wins can be stored in a very simple Player class which looked like this:

```
public class Player{
    private String name;
    private int totalScore;
    private int totalWins;
}
```

---

**Dynamic Multi-player**

I tried to keep the solution as short and simple as possible for your understanding. But if you want the program to dynamically take in `n` number of players. The same program flow still applies.

In step 4, you can do it as:

```
int numOfPlayers = 2; //can receive this from user input

ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
for(int x=0; x<numOfPlayers; x++)
    numOfPlayers.add(new Player("Player " + (x+1)));

for(int x=0; x<numOfRounds; x++){
    for(int y=0; y<players.size(); y++)  //iterate through all players
        rollDice(players.get(y));
    decideWinner(players);               //decide the winner from all the players
}
```

Comment: would this work for more than 2 players, as the number of players and rounds are input by the user

Comment: @astrnm I thought about that too, but I fear it may complicate the solution. Instead of inserting the player object directly, he can insert a list of player objects and it will still work the same. Anyway, I think I will update it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it. I've been trying to implement this code for a day and I am getting closer thanks to you. But I am new at java and I am a bit confused, when you said  _**1.Implement dice rolling for one player first. (Can do it in a method)
2.Call the above implemented method for 2nd player's dice roll.
3.Decide winner**_ I don't really know how to do it. Again you have been really helpful, thank you

Comment: @astrnm Actually you have already implemented most of the things I mentioned. I was just emphasizing the usefulness of doing things 1 step at a time. Instead of dumping all your logic in the main, you can split them into smaller parts - methods. So whenever you need to implement the same logic again (e.g. dice rolling), you don't have to recode everything. You simply call the method.

Comment: @astrnm If it solves your problem, you may accept **one** solution which helped you most by clicking the hollow looking tick beside that solution. You get 2 reputation points by doing so.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I've been trying to implement your code into mine and I cant figure out how to do it, could you help me implement it, thank you

Comment: I can't help you implement it. But if you have specific question, I see if I can answer you.

Comment: If not, we can talk in Skype.

Comment: in the Dynamic Multi-player code, should I create a separate method for the dice array and the dice winner?. and then replace the entire main method with the Dynamic Multi-player code?. how do I create a separate method for the dice winner ?

Comment: If you have a game class which drives everything, you can create the decideWinner() method in there. If you are running most of your code from the main(), you can have another `public static` method for `decideWinner()` where it co-exist alongside with your `main()`. Don't worry about what to create as a method for now. Just ensure your code runs. All the others are secondary.

Comment: When I create the decideWinner() method it runs outside the rounds loop and player loop

Comment: this is my skype: *rastionre* let me know when you are aviable

Comment: Can we talk in skype?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to solve this, I would add two counters like `int count = 0` and increment them: one every time there is a victory (for ex.: `if(victory) { c++ }`)and the other through the expression `count = count + points`.
Remember to implement these ints at the beginning or the for loop will reset count1 and count2 to 0.